# erase object from std list of object pointers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, erase, stdlist

I have a class Lobby which handles a list of Players(which is an Abstract Class, only pure virtual methods) now i tried  to do the following:

```
    ...    
    std::list<Player*> list;
    ...
    Lobby::Lobby (std::string name, unsigned int size){
        m_size = size;
        m_name = name;
        std::list<Player*> list(size);
    }
    ...
    void Lobby::removePlayer(int playerID){
    for (std::list<Player*>::iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); it++){
    if ((*it)->id == playerID){
        it = list.erase(it);
    }
}
}
    ...
```

---

I always get two erros, and have no glew how to solve them:

```
error C2259: 'Member' : cannot instantiate abstract
    class
```

*I am almost new in C++, but thought that if i use a list of pointers of the base class it should work?!*

```
  IntelliSense: no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Member>>>" to "std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Member *>>>" exists**
```

Comment: `std::remove_if` will do `removePlayer` for you. It's likely you want a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Player>>` or a `boost::ptr_vector<Player>`, though.

Comment: Code and error are unrelated... What is `Member` ? where is your `std::list<Member*>` ?

Comment: you have a conceptual problem in your loop: if you erase an object from the lsit, you implicitly iterate it twice and skip one object. Since `it = list.erase(it);` will set the iterator to the next object position and `it++` is called immediately after that. so it only works if there is maximum one player with the given id in the list. If that's the case you can add a `return` or a `break` after finding and erasing that object ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few points:
first, to your problem. I can see nothing wrong with the code you provided, except thet it is not the code you are compiling. Looks like, you have a list of Members*, and you refer to it as Member.
Second, Look at remove_if. it ill do the work for you.
Last, looks like you have a memory leak here. you remove instance of player from the list, but do nor release it's memory (calling delete)

Comment: thanks for the advice, you are absolutly right with the last hint! i forgot to call "delete *it;"

Answer (score 0):

I can tell from the error messages that you don't show us the actual code. The second message tells us you are having a `list<Member*>` and maybe a `list<Member>`, or at least iterators of the two. A `list<Member>` could also account for the first error, since the `list` operations try to construct `Member` objects which is not possible.

My guess is, that you forgot the `*` somewhere.

You will also want to look at your objects' lifetimes. C++ has no Garbage Collector, so just erasing the pointers from that list won't kill the `Member` objects themselves. Better use smart pointers like chris suggests in his comment.